# (Mongoose) В чем причина ошибки: "Hex is not a function?"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
var test = res[0]._id.toHexString(); // получаем hex-строку
require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId(test); // получаем ObjectId
```

При вызове ObjectId выдает ошибку: 
Type error: hex is not a function.

Comment: _В чем причина ошибки: “Hex is not a function?”_ - как ни странно, в том, что `hex` - это не функция.

Comment: _require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId(test); // получаем ObjectId_ - проверь в справке что именно можно передавать в эту функцию, и что передаешь ты.

Comment: @Grundy Там принимают строку (hex-string)